# Configuring GSuite to work with route 53 - "MX record doesn't have 2 fields" error

Tags: amazon-web-services, gmail, amazon-route53, google-workspace, mail-server

I'm doing my best to follow GSuite's out of date instructions for routing emails to Gmail via a AWS Route 53 hosted zone (i.e. domain). Here are the outdated instructions:

[image]

I set the Values as instructed:

[image]

And I see:

> Error occurred
> Bad request.
> (InvalidChangeBatch 400: MXRRDATANotTwoFields (MX record doesn't have 2 fields) encountered with '')

[image]

So it will not allow me to create the records.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this exact scenario when I used the new AWS Route 53 interface.

To resolve it I selected the `use the old console.` link from the top.

[image]

I then pasted the values below and it worked.

```
1 aspmx.l.google.com.
5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
5 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
10 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
10 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
```

For now use the old console for doing this would be my suggestion.

Comment: Hi Chris thanks for the help. I figured it out at the same time. I can also confirm the old console doesn't have the problem. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem, glad its "solved" for you. I have submitted feedback via the console to Route 53 team so hopefully this will get fixed :)

Comment: I used the new console and just prefixed with the numerals: 1 5 5 10 10

Comment: @haxpanel are you still experiencing the issue above? I could no longer reproduce it, just wondered if you could provide any steps to reproduce it now :)

Comment: @ChrisWilliams I used the old console which worked. Did not spend too much time on trying the new one after seeng the error I went to SO. :)

Answer (score 55):

I had this problem with the new AWS console, but it turns out the problem was me. I had not read the instructions carefully enough.

There needed to be a numeric value (not explained) before the domain name or ip address in the value input. When I added the number, this worked for me in the new console.

[image]

Comment: I had this problem too. Also you need to create all your MX records in one record. Even though my mail site said "add new MX records" plural. You don't create multiple MX records, you put all this in the same textbox on separate lines: 10 mydomain.com 20 mydomain.com 50 mydomain.com

Comment: Also found that this solves the same problem when using other mails servers, in my case adding a Microsoft mail server record.

Comment: Just got this to work at the date of this comment. All in the same textbox for the mx record. Priority number followed by a space and hit enter until you enter all the records provided by Google Workspace.

Answer (score 6):

You need to enter more than one value. This is working fine

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There's something wrong with the new Route 53 console. I tried the exact same things in the old console and it worked immediately.

I hope AWS fix this soon. For anyone experiencing this issue in the mean time, try simply reverting to the old console by clicking the link on the left hand panel:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

So actually what MX record consists of is a priority and a host. The smaller the number the higher the priority. You can look it up on google as well.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the cause of the problem is the nature or length of the whitespace between the priority and the host on each line. Reducing all this whitespace - on each line - down to a single space resolved the matter for me.

Answer (score 0):

This seem to worked for me in Route 53

[image]

[image]

https://support.google.com/domains/answer/3251241?hl=en&ref_topic=6293345#zippy=%2Cset-up-email-forwarding-with-custom-name-servers